# Docker - Run app on swarm manager (cant connect)

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm, docker-machine

TLDR version:

***How can I verify/set ports 7946 & 4789 on my swarm node so that I can view my application running from my docker-machine?***

Complete question:

I am going through the docker tutorials and am on step 4
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#accessing-your-cluster

When I get to accessing your cluster section. It says that I should just be able to grab the ip address from one of my nodes displayed using docker-machine ls. I run that command, see the IP, grab it and put it into my browser (or alternatively use curl) and i receive the error

```
This site can’t be reached

192.168.99.100 refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Below this step it has a note saying that before you enable swarm mode, assuming they mean when you run:

```
docker-machine ssh myvm1 "docker swarm init --advertise-addr <myvm1 ip>"
```

You should check the following port settings

```
Having connectivity trouble?

Keep in mind that in order to use the ingress network in the swarm, you need to have the following ports open between the swarm nodes before you enable swarm mode:

Port 7946 TCP/UDP for container network discovery.
Port 4789 UDP for the container ingress network.
```

I've spent the last few days going through documentation, redoing the steps and trying everything I can to have this work but nothing has been successful.

Can anyone explain/provide documentation to show me how to view/set these ports, or explain if I am missing some other important information?

***UPDATE***

I wasn't able to get swarm working, so I decided to just run everything from a docker-compose.yml file. Here is the code I used below:

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  www:
build: .
ports:
  - "80:80"
links:
  - db
depends_on:
  - db
volumes:
  - .:/opt/www

db:
image: mysql:5.7
volumes:
  - /var/lib/mysql
restart: always
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: supersecure
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
  MYSQL_USER: jake
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: supersecure
```

and a Dockerfile located in the same directory containing the following:

```
# A simple Flask app container.
FROM python:2.7
LABEL maintainer="your name here"

# Place app in container.
ADD . /opt/www
WORKDIR /opt/www

# Install dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80
ENV FLASK_APP index.py
ENV FLASK_DEBUG 1
CMD python index.py
```

you'll need to create any other files which are referenced in these two files (example requirements.txt & index.py) but those are all in the same directory as the dockerfile & docker-compose.yml files. Please comment if anyone has questions

Comment: Are u using Linux, Windows or Mac?

Comment: I’m running on a Mac

Comment: I am stuck on the same issue from last 3 days. i am using windows and docker tool box. i have created a swarm cluster but unable to hit.

Comment: @VikasVats The temporary solution I went was to just create a docker-compose file with my information in it, then run it with docker-compose build / docker-compose up. I'll post the code I used to get python to run with mysql as an update.. if you don't need to use swarm, just avoid it I guess... not a really satisfactory answer but if this is a blocking issue, might be worth it to just avoid it